# How to send transparent png with sendphoto in telegram bot?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, node-telegram-bot-api

Telegram always adds the white background to my transparent .png images when I send them via sendphoto. But how to keep them transparent as the source?

Comment: Your image IS transparent.  Telegram has simply chosen to display it over a white background.  That's a Telegram design decision that you cannot change.

Answer (score 0):

Transparent PNGs won't work with `sendPhoto`, compression removes transparency. Use `sendDocument` to maintain the transparent background.